# how to return value in another cell if a cell contains certain text in excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

how to return value in another cell if a cell contains certain text in excel using VBA. 
For suppose if any cell in range B14 to Z14 contains "Jun" then the cell above that should be populated with Q4, and so on.

Comment: You should use If statement. Check cells value and populate a string in case of 'true'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub PopulateCells()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = Range("B14:Z14")

    For Each c In rng
        If InStr(1, c.Value, "Jun") > 0 Then c.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Q4" 
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It Works , Thank you (y) .

Answer (score 0):

In **B13** enter:

```
=IF(B14="Jun",$Q$4,"")
```

and copy across.